# gtk minimum size

Tags: c++, python, c, gtk, pygtk

Is there an easy way to request that a GTK widget have a minimum width/height? I know you can do it on the column of a `TreeView`, but is it available for general widgets?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For C/C++: [gtk_widget_set_size_request()](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk/unstable/GtkWidget.html#gtk-widget-set-size-request)

> Sets the minimum size of a widget; that is, the widget's size request will be width by height.

PyGTK: [def set_size_request(width, height)](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtkwidget.html#method-gtkwidget--set-size-request)

Comment: At the time of the post (12 Oct 2010), it was the way to do it.

Comment: Is there a better way now?

Comment: This continues to be the better way.