# How to set width of GtkComboBoxText?

Tags: gtk, pygtk

I have GtkComboBoxText in which first Item text is small and last item Text is too long. Because of the long Text width set to long text length. I want to set its width to small text length. How do I achieve this ?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I was trying to to set it through Glade. But didn't find any option. I tried set_wrap_width () but it's not helping.

Comment: possible duplicate of [gtk minimum size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3916762/gtk-minimum-size)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately [`set_wrap_width()`](https://developer.gnome.org/pygtk/2.24/class-gtkcombobox.html#method-gtkcombobox--set-wrap-width) doesn't seem to have anything to do with controlling the width of the widget. I think you want to set the [`width-chars`](https://developer.gnome.org/pygtk/2.24/class-gtkcellrenderer.html#properties-gtkcellrenderer) and possibly the `wrap-width` or `ellipsize` & `ellpisize-set` properties of the cell renderer that the combo box uses to display the items in it. You can get a list of the renderers (there should only be one item in the list for a simple GtkComboBoxText) with [`get_cells()`](https://developer.gnome.org/pygtk/2.24/class-gtkcelllayout.html#method-gtkcelllayout--get-cells) and then find the GtkCellRendererText and set the properties that you want on it.